# Mosek not playing nice with CVXPY and joblib

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib, cvxpy, mosek

Getting some weird behavior with MOSEK, CVXPY and joblib. Trying to parallelize some jobs in Python (without even calling Mosek) and getting errors like

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Tcl_InitNotifier: unable to start notifier thread
```

within each process that I'm calling from joblib. This only occurs after installing Mosek via

```
pip install Mosek
```

in my virtualenv. Nothing else has changed in the code (and I'm not specifying Mosek as the solver in CVXPY). If I `pip uninstall Mosek` and use any other solver in my CVXPY optimization the code runs fine. Any ideas as to what's happening? Seems like the python Mosek package/ Mosek itself doesn't work in a multithreading/ multiprocess environment?

Comment: Mosek ships with its own libtbb, that's the only even remotely related possible reason I can think of. However it still looks very strange. Please write an email to Mosek support with the exact environment specifications and steps to reproduce and there we will have a look at it.

Comment: Another possibility is that ``pip install Mosek`` caused some of your packages to change versions because of dependencies, and that is causing the issue.